# Generate new image from rotated rectangle in python

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am working on the export feature for an image viewer. I have 4 points on an image that always form a rectangle, but the rectangle might be rotated. I also have the rotation of the rectangle. Now I want to generate a new image from the input image and the values I explained above. How can I achieve this is python ? The image below might make it a lot more clearer what I actually want to do:
[image]

Comment: you could do the inverse rotation to the image and keep the rectangle straight. Are you rotating the rectangle around it's center?

Comment: no clue how to use PIL for that. -- use OpenCV, `warpAffine` and appropriately calculated affine transformation matrix. it's not complicated. you could use `getRotationMatrix2D` or calculate the values on your own.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz can you specify further how exactly I could use an affine transformation in my case? I looked it up in the opencv docs and it all looks very overwhelming coming from virtually no previous knowledge in image processing

Comment: how exactly is your rotated rectangle defined? I know you have the corner points, but those are calculated. what are they derived from? if you're unsure, I'd suggest a center point, an angle, and a width and height for the box, symmetric so the center is the center of the box, not placed anywhere else in the box.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I ultimately want to use this in the export feature of an image viewer I am building. I want to give the user the ability to save what they are currently seeing in the image viewer to an actual image file. I am getting the roatation and the coordinates for the rectangle from a builtin "get_in_view()" function from the gui library I am using. In the end I just have a list with my 4 points, the rotation and the path to the image to perform the image manipulation on.

Comment: ok, so it's four points. good. do you want to preserve scale (have just rotation+translation) or does the output need to be a specific size? I'll build an answer later. if you don't want a solution using OpenCV, let me know, because I'll use OpenCV. the principles probably apply to PIL too but I'm not terribly familiar with that library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will be using the following picture for example:

[image]

### Creating the wanted rectangle

Informative, you say you are getting the rectangle itself I am just creating here for the example as follows:

```
# creating source points - informative
xx = [50, 50, 200, 200]
yy = [30, 60, 30, 60]
alpha  = np.pi/6  # 30 degrees
rotMat = np.array([[np.cos(alpha), -1*np.sin(alpha)],
                   [np.sin(alpha), np.cos(alpha)]])
src_pts = []
for [x, y] in zip(xx,yy):
    src_pts.append(rotMat.dot(np.array([x, y])) + np.array([3, 7]))
src_pts = np.array(src_pts)
```

After generating the rectangle coordinate:

```
[[ 31.30127019  57.98076211]
 [ 16.30127019  83.96152423]
 [161.20508076 132.98076211]
 [146.20508076 158.96152423]]
```

we get the sides by checking if the dot product of the vectors is 0 indicating 90 degrees between them:

```
if np.isclose((src_pts[1] - src_pts[0]).dot(src_pts[2] - src_pts[0]), 0):
    side1 = np.around(np.linalg.norm(src_pts[1] - src_pts[0]), 2)
    side2 = np.around(np.linalg.norm(src_pts[2] - src_pts[0]), 2)
    dst_points = np.array([[0, 0],[0, side1], [side2, 0]])
    src_pts    = src_pts[[0, 1, 2]]
```

As a sanity check we can print the sides and see that:

```
print(side1, side2)  # 30.0 150.0 ; match the original rectangle sides
```

And we can see the three points in the picture and the new location after the rotation + shift (Affine transformation)
[image]

Where we can see the original points in blue and the rotated + shifted points in orange.

### Affine transformation

Now we can find the [affine transformation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d61/tutorial_warp_affine.html) (rotation + translation) to take us there using opencv:

```
# finding affine transformation
affine = cv2.getAffineTransform(np.float32(src_pts), np.float32(dst_points))
print(affine)
#[[  0.86602543   0.50000001 -56.09807697]
#[ -0.49999998   0.8660254  -34.56217897]]
```

To check that we got a correct affine transformation and that our coordinate points were alighted we can see that the left `2X2` matrix corresponds to a rotation matrix (in this case the 30 degrees we rotated to create the reectangle) and the right `2X1` vector is the shift or translation vector.

### Applying the transformation

All is set up for the grand finale, tranforming the picture and cropping. All is done nicely using opencv:

```
# Applying affine transform to the image
img_new = cv2.warpAffine(img, affine, dsize=(int(side2), int(side1)))
```

Plotting the result we get:
[image]